# Add Attribute to Base Event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, user-controls

I'm working on a class that is derived from the `UserControl` class. This class adds the attributes `[Browsable(false)]` and `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` to the event `TextChanged` which is inherited from the `Control` class.

My new control is comparable to a `TabPage`; it is used inside of another class that is comparable to the `TabControl`. The reason this is important is because it means that I need the user of the control to be able to access this event. In .NET reflector, we see that the `TabPage` control (which inherits from `Panel`, which also adds these two attributes) "overrides" these two attributes with the following code:

```
[Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
public event EventHandler TextChanged;
```

I copied this into my project, and as far as I can tell it works correctly, but the compiler gives me a warning: "'System.Windows.Forms.Frameset.FunctionPanel.TextChanged' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.TextChanged'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.". I do not want to hide the old TextChanged event; I just want to remove the `Browsable(false)` attribute. While hiding the old event seems to get the job done on the surface, it seems like an ugly and roundabout way of doing it. Is there a way to do this without hiding the old event? And if not, is there a way to get the compiler to stop giving me a warning for it?

Thanks in advance,
Brandon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following. It should be safe in all the possible situations:

```
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public new event EventHandler TextChanged {
        add {
            base.TextChanged += value;
        }
        remove {
            base.TextChanged -= value;
        }
    }
```